# docker how to list all unused images without pruning

Tags: docker

[image]

I've found that `docker system df` shows the large RECLAIMABLE space for me.
In order to save the space, I know that `docker image prune -a` will remove all unused images.
However, I'd like to know the list before pruning for the safety.
Is there any way to list all images those are currently not being used by any container? (The images that will be deleted by `docker image prune -a`)
I have searched for it but there are only pruning methods, no listing methods.

Comment: pruning images should always be safe. If you are ever in a situation where you cant afford to delete an image, you did something wrong. There should be a Dockerfile for each of them or an upstream repositry. So you can always get your images back.

Comment: You can see this post.
@GPuri https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414299/how-to-check-for-unuse-images-for-your-docker-containers

Comment: @TheFool (Name checks out) If what you state were true there would be no need for images because all you would need to run a container would be the Docker file. Meanwhile, back in the real world, building or downloading docker images will, at least, take time; possibly a very long time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So to fetch all the unused docker images without actually pruning them, you could do the following

1. Fetch all the images belonging to the running containers(which are not stopped or exited)
2. Fetch all the images on the machine
3. Then filter the images in step 1 from step 2

Below are the shell commands

```
runningImages=$(docker ps --format {{.Image}})
docker images --format "{{.ID}} {{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}" | grep -v "$runningImages"
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this command to show all of images:

```
docker images -a
```

You can find unused images using the command:

```
docker images -f dangling=true
```

and just a list of their IDs:

```
docker images -q -f dangling=true
```

In case you want to delete them:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

Comment: This is not correct. Images can be unused but not dangling.